# asp.net detect iOS/Android deeplinking failure

Tags: c#, android, ios, asp.net, deep-linking

I am working on a web project which involves using a custom url scheme to launch the iOS/Android application from the browser using deep linking / intents and a custom uri scheme mycom://etc. The feature works without issue but when the user does not have the application installed they see a "webpage not found" error, which is not a good user experience.

in my project I am calling

```
Response.Redirect(targetUri);
```

but I know it is not possible to detect that a redirect has failed.

Is there another way to attempt navigating to the deep link and then handle the case where it fails?

Answer (score 1):

This used to be a good approach (you would attempt to redirect to the app, and then immediately redirect somewhere else if/when the app failed to launch). This still works on Android, but as you've discovered, [Apple has decided that URI schemes are a bad option for iOS deep linking](https://blog.branch.io/ios-9.2-redirection-update-uri-scheme-and-universal-links).

The new best approach is to use [iOS Universal Links](https://blog.branch.io/how-to-setup-universal-links-to-deep-link-on-apple-ios-9). These don't rely on URI schemes so you'll need to do some additional set up work to support them, but Apple has made it pretty clear that this is the new preferred way to launch installed apps with a graceful fallback method for when the app is not yet installed. You can make the configuration process a lot simpler if you use a free deep link service like [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team).